# TypeScript adjust interface based on generic value

Tags: typescript

I am trying to adjust a TypeScript interface based on certain keys in an object.

I have an object coming from GraphQL that looks something like this,

```json
{
  "vamm": {
    "__typename": "Vamm",
    "stats": {
      "__typename": "VammStats",
      "fee": {
        "amount": "0.01",
        "__typename": "Amount"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote a function which accepts these GraphQL data objects and recursively looks for a key of `__typename` equaling `Amount`. Upon finding a match, that object will be replaced with a class.

```js
interface QueryObject {
  __typename: string
  [key: string]: unknown
}

type FormattedQueryData<Data> = unknown

const formatQueryData = <Data>(data: Data): FormattedQueryData<Data> => {
  if (typeof data === "object") {
    if ("__typename" in data) {
      const queryObject = data as unknown as QueryObject

      if (queryObject.__typename === "Amount") {
        const queryAmount = queryObject as QueryAmount

        return new Amount(queryAmount.amount)
      }
    }

    const accumulator: Record<string, unknown> = {}

    for (const key in data) {
      accumulator[key] = formatQueryData(data[key])
    }

    return accumulator
  }

  return data
}
```

This function will return an object with an identical shape except for the value of `fee`, which will no longer equal,

```js
{
  "fee": {
    "amount": "0.01",
    "__typename": "Amount"
  }
}
```

but instead it will equal the below value.

```js
{
  "fee": Amount // class
}
```

Is there a way to update the `FormattedQueryData` type to reflect the returned object?

[Here is a TypeScript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECCC2B7ArgOwC7QN4ChrQCMBLAcwDll4CBTAJwC5oJ1ajUSc9phFVnbkwdIloAKAG5gQyao35sSASmxd86ABZEIAOmLlKNWtAC80SdOpcAvjhs426OgDMwwatACSqAA7JMufEl4eEYA-GgAfQj0AE9valQweFkmFgVVVLB0CFCM-CjY+MTkuTT2POgnahSw8PCklAxS1nK6uoK4hKSU+Va2mzqB6Bs7B2dXdwBRAA94oWoAEwB5P19-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-AOMwVxgEoZBwGEBhoAAJUNEQFlvXoSGxITUDdETUOwOw6icERsMC6BbRiRj5xYzS2mC0LwpEG07UdCEcpgn8EJvECwRqmJHR8wZ-MnadZ1E4AQvgMKshEaxLOs-rmLBH18oa2Cdz-Ux5qaoMb1vAc-GAn4-kBEEwR8oA)

Comment: do you need the return type annotation at all? It appears this function is returning object of different types right? The result of Amount as well as the accumulator?

Comment: some inputs and expected outputs would be helpful

Comment: Please provide a plaintext self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/Wy4Mxm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: I updated the question with the expected input and output along with included a playground link which has some more clear examples.

Comment: I don't understand how you go from input to output... The Amount class doesn't even share any properties with the `fee` property...

Comment: The Amount class in the playground link is just a placeholder to satisfy the errors. The queried data can be thought of as a JSON representation of an 'amount'. While the Amount class only needs that JSON object for instantiation. But I'm not sure why these details are relevant for solving the issue...

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nr50Vw) meet your needs... please test against use cases you care about.  If it works for you I can write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?  Note that you might need to say "@jcalz" to get my attention; SO does not always notify

Comment: @jcalz yes thats perfect. its so simple, that i missed it... my attempt was much more complicated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach here would be to make `FormattedQueryData<T>` a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) that converts `{amount: string, __typename: string}` to `Amount`, and otherwise [maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) each object property via `FormattedQueryData<T>`.  Like this:

```
type FormattedQueryData<T> = T extends { amount: string, __typename: string } ?
  Amount : { [K in keyof T]: FormattedQueryData<T[K]> };
```

Note that mapped of the form `{[K in keyof T]: ...}` don't change primitive `T` types, so if `T` is `string` you just get `string`.

Let's see that it does what you want to `Input`:

```
type FormattedInput = FormattedQueryData<Input>;
/* type FormattedInput = {
    vamm: {
        __typename: string;
        stats: {
            __typename: string;
            fee: Amount;
        };
    };
} */
```

That's the same as your `ExpectedOutput` type.  So we can write this without error

```
const formattedData: ExpectedOutput = formatQueryData<Input>(graphqlData); // okay
```

And in face that type specification of `Input` is unnecessary, since it gets inferred:

```
const formattedData: ExpectedOutput = formatQueryData(graphqlData); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECCC2B7ArgOwC7QN4ChrQCMBLAcwDll4CBTAJwC5oJ1ajUSc9phFVnbkwdIloAKAG5gQyao35sSASmxd86ABZEIAOmLlKNWtAC80SdOpcAvjhs426OgDMwwatACSqAA7JMufEl4eEYA-GgAfQj0AE9valQweFkmFgVVVLB0CFCM-CjY+MTkuTT2POgnahSw8PCklAxS1nK6uoK4hKSU+Va2mzqB6Bs7B2dXdwBRAA94oWoAEwB5P19-LiCQlXbozuKeso465iyc7baOou7m9LbK6sYERvQMoZHOHj5MElowb3UAI4gAAiWTAJnOACJNpDcnVIZcuslYdBIQA1JLwSEAGgykJO2RRtXCCN2V2RjHRmIAyuhTjiKpCqtQiRV8JCGmh0CjIQAGbS8gCMDLu7MR+x5Ty5kIqQ3wb1snDGtBcbmgAEUZLQYksCAArahCc7i66pFpHaAAbQA1tQYjd2ABdRhoa2oRAAd1QivsGHGas1dBiUow0Go00cqAWMED2t1BqNYRNJVRIe5XE5TTN6TshXcADERPAso4FrGYqC6QAeAAqAD4ITWwxGEtHsNBM+gHSRsZEyUiDubhtAAPxcNPQUJWgDS0DY0FtMUQTmgNed0ELtGL6FL5crYFrlunjobVgA3Jw8xuiyXFl41hDN9vd1qK2Cq-e-HWLwB6ABU0BXk+t4LJ+mCmMSmxwqKyaDgoF6ipk2TQYh+T9vs3YIah+DMo8SBclhdznq8F5WNAf4-h8vDMJUN7oHuYIQrW2J1qICxgowNaKIwwE7osDHVvWJgNmERArqIebLtA7F0iYximJCiD6oa3LKMSYnQKIpJ5hKc6oNJYJqRUnw0QCr7xipEIyeCkDQK67peh2MbmcpQicHcGmiGZQYWUI2iwXJClppCRmISZmDedqE6mJFOquZgtnlmm7mirQ1DoMgtD6ag1AenA+EYF5r5ptonbKLZYCoDEsqvCl+DhR2wDAJQyDgMIDDQAASoaIgLFWvQ9nZqBup6qANhBdh1E4IiaQ1i56QZdKhW0rjNfArVZCINp2o6ELTVuWQCWAbFgttMSOootUZGlGVZY1a0be1TkdlV1gpTdmX6dZz2VdVdgNftz6LPujAzHMpYrOgD6mIDh2vvuH4+F+og-H8gIgoZZ7QD+P7QIg1pgNVAPAqDswqYskPQ7RB30fDYIo78-xAvuyg43jBPVUAA)